# Failed: Template parse errors: 'app-header' is not a known element

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular8

```
homepage.module.ts

import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HomepageComponent } from "./homepage.component";
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomepageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [HomepageComponent],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class HomepageModule {}


shared-module.ts

import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header/header.component";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SharedModule {}


homepage.component.html

<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"></app-header>


app.module.ts

import { HomepageModule } from "./homepage/homepage.module";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HomepageModule,
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

while running karma , i am getting the errors . : 
Failed: Template parse errors:
'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

Do i need to add anything in the homepage.component.spec file ?

Comment: Yes, you need to meke sure the testing module contains everything needed, just as a normal module.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to see if your component who must use "app-header" and HeaderComponent also are imported in your module
- Try to see if one of your components is not imported in 2 or more modules